# Contractions on a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear map defined on a subspace $S$ of some Euclidean vector space $V$, such that
$$
d(T(v_1),T(v_2))\leq d(v_1,v_2) \quad \text{for } v_1,v_2\in S
$$
where $d(v_1,v_2)$ is the Euclidean distance on $V$. Is there always a linear map $T'$ defined on $V$ such that 
$$
d(T'(v_1),T'(v_2))\leq d(v_1,v_2) \quad \text{for all } v_1, v_2\in V
$$
and that $T'(v)=T(v)$ for all $v\in S$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is always possible in $\Bbb R^n$ (finite dimensional Euclidean space).  In particular, we may note that $V = S \oplus S^\perp$, and so each $v \in V$ can be uniquely expressed as $v = v_S + v^\perp$ with $v_S \in S$ and $v_\perp \in S^\perp$.  We may then define
$$
T'(v) = T'(v_S + v^\perp) = T'(v_S)
$$
Verify that this $T'$ satisfies the requirements given.

Comment: I see a problem: $d(T'(v_1),T'(v_2))=d(T(v_{S1}),T(v_{S2}))\leq d(v_{S1},v_{S2})\neq d(v_{1},v_{2})$.

Comment: @NessunDorma note that $$d(v_{1S},v_{2S}) = \|v_{1S} - v_{2S}\| = \|(v_1 - v_2)_S\| \leq \|v_1 - v_2\| = d(v_1,v_2)$$