# Extension of contractions on a Banach subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

This question is related to [Contractions on a subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191149/contractions-on-a-subspace) but on a Banach space instead a vector space.

Let $T$ be a linear map defined on a subspace $S$ of some Banach space $V$, such that
$$
d(T(v_1),T(v_2))≤d(v_1,v_2)\quad \text{for } v_1,v_2\in S 
$$
where $d(v_1,v_2)=\|v_1-v_2\|$ is the norm induced distance on $V$. Can we say somethig about the existence or not of a contractive linear extension $T'$, defined on $V$ such that
$$
d(T'(v_1),T'(v_2))≤d(v_1,v_2)\quad \text{for all } v_1,v_2\in V
$$
and that $T'(v)=T(v)$ for all $v\in S$?

Comment: Shalop may be right.  What is the codomain of $T$?

Comment: Yes, the Shalop's idea sounds good, but my doubt is also the codomain of $T$, which is $S$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Aweygan Ah yes of course you are both correct, Hahn-Banach only applies when the codomain is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, silly me. I don't know if this claim is true for any Banach space, however I found it is true at least for Hilbert spaces. Indeed, one first extends $T$ to $\overline S$ as before. Then let $P:V \to \overline S$ be the projection onto $\overline S$, and consider the map $T':=T \circ P$. Since $\|P\| \leq 1$ and $\|T\| \leq 1$ one finds that $\|TP\| \leq \|T\| \|P\| \leq 1$. In general, I think you can mimic this argument as long as $\overline S$ has a complemented subspace.

Comment: And Shalop's ideas work for $V$ a Banach space when $\overline S$ is complemented in $V$.

Comment: Right, $1$-complemented subspaces, at least. See Michelle's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, linear operators do not admit norm-preserving extension (Hahn-Banach theorem applies only to functionals). I'll mention two  special cases when they do:

1. $V$ is a space in which every subspace $S$ is $1$-complemented, i.e., there exists a norm-$1$ idempotent $E:V\to V$ with range $S$. Then $T\circ E$ is the desired extension. Such spaces include: (a) Hilbert spaces; (b) two-dimensional normed spaces.
2. $V$ is an *injective Banach space*: one way to describe such a space is that every collection of pairwise-intersecting closed balls has nonempty intersection.  Examples include $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$.  See [Equivalent definitions of Injective Banach Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470869/equivalent-definitions-of-injective-banach-spaces)

---

Here is an explicit example of an operator without norm-preserving extension. Let $V=\ell_1^4$, the $4$-dimensional space with $\ell_1$ norm. Let $S=\{x\in V : \sum x_k = 0\}$, a codimension-1 subspace. Consider the operator $T:V\to V$ with the matrix (in standard basis) 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\tag1$$
I claim that:

- the norm of the restriction $T_{|S}$  is strictly less than $3$;
- any extension of $T_{|S}$ to a map on $V$ has norm at least $3$.

**First claim**. The norm of $T_{|S}$ is the maximum of norms $\left\|\sum_{k=1}^4 c_k v_k\right\|_1$ where $v_1,\dots, v_4$ are the columns of  matrix $A$, and the coefficients satisfy $\sum c_k=0$ and $\sum |c_k| =  1$. It is clear that at least two of the coefficients $c_k$ must be nonzero. Whether they have same sign or opposite sign, forming the sum $\sum_{k=1}^4 c_k v_k$ entails *cancellation*, numbers of different signs added together. (This is because for any pair of columns of $A$, some row has elements of different sign and some row has elements of the same sign). Hence, 
$$
\left\|\sum_{k=1}^4 c_k v_k\right\|_1 < \sum_{k=1}^4 |c_k| \|v_k\|_1 = 3 
$$

**Second claim**. Let $T'$ be any extension of $T_{|S}$. Then $T'-T$ vanishes on $S$, which means it is a rank-one operator with matrix of the form
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} a&a&a&a \\ b&b&b&b \\ c&c&c&c \\ d&d&d&d \end{pmatrix}
\tag2$$
Since every row of $A$ has median zero, adding any constant to that row does not decrease its $\ell_1$ norm. Therefore, the sum of absolute values of all entries of $A+B$ is at least $12$ (the value of this sum for $A$). Hence, at least one column of $A+B$ has $\ell_1$ norm $\ge 3$, and the claim is proved.

Comment: For those curious, the $\ell_1\to\ell_1$ norm of $T_{|S}$  is exactly $2$.